# On_options_item_selected method Explanation

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, drawerlayout

I'm creating a Navigation Drawer/Menu by following a tutorial on YouTube. While everything works just fine and i get most of the inner workings of the methods etc. that we are using, the onOptionsItemSelected method baffles me a bit. Consider the following part of my code :

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Where mToggle is a new ActionBarDrawerToggle.
From the youtuber's explanation i understand that we can use this to make our DrawerToggleButton(3 parallel lines) toggle the state of the drawer(open/closed). But is this correct? I mean , we are passing in a MenuItem item as a parameter which is used to know which item was clicked..but is this toggle button considered a MenuItem(since it's not inside the side-menu?)?

Thank you in advance! :D

Comment: As far as i know it depends on the way you are implementing Nav drawer. You can also place toggle functionality in onClick of any view as well.

Comment: Provided you have everything setup correctly for it, yes, clicking the toggle button will fire `onOptionsItemSelected()`, which is why `ActionBarDrawerToggle` has its own method by that name. The toggle will simply check if the `MenuItem`'s ID is `android.R.id.home`, and will open/close the drawer as appropriate, if so. Though it's not really part of the options menu, that's just how they designed the home button's functionality, and `ActionBarDrawerToggle` kinda piggybacks on top of that.